# Hooking my own filesystem functions for RTEMS

Tags: function, filesystems, hook, rtems

I am working on a file system for the RTEMS OS.  My question is how can I have the opendir, readdir, and closedir functions found in the unistd.h library redirect to my own opendir, readdir, and closedir functions for my file system? i.e. How can I hook them into RTEMS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You would have gotten a quicker response from the rtema mailing list. The answer is that each filesystem has to provide a structure with a set of entry points which largely correspond to POSIX file I/O system calls. There are multiple filesystem types already in RTEMS and you should just follow the same pattern.

So look in cpukit/libfs and ask more on rtems.org